# Windows 7 32-bit on 64 bit processor, Will 64 bit games work?

Tags: windows-7, memory, cpu, 64-bit, 32-bit

I recently installed a brand new 64 bit processor into my system (very happy about it), but I have a 32 bit operating system.

I want to run 64 bit games, but I don't know if I need to upgrade my OS as well.

I'd also like to know if I can allocate higher amounts of RAM to run other, also RAM/CPU intensive games.

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to upgrade your OS to 64-bit to take advantage of your 64-bit processor. As for the RAM, you may want to look up Physical Address Extension, assuming you do not upgrade your OS to 64-bit.

Comment: If you want to run 64-bit programs why did you install a 32-bit operating system?  The same license for `Windows 7` can be used for 32-bit or 64-bit installation.  This is different then Windows XP where there were specific individual versions (`Windows XP` (32-bit) and `Windows XP 64-bit Edition`).  The maximum amount of memory a 32-bit version of Windows can allocate is 4 GB.  If you want to allocate more then that then install a 64-bit operating system.

Answer (score 5):

no you can't run 64-bit applications on a 32-bit OS.

The issue is not the processor but the OS itself

You would have to **REINSTALL** 64-bit OS, **it's not an upgrade** but a reinstall.

Recommendation : Before you jump into switching the OS please check support matrix of the game you are using and see which versions of the OS are supported.

[How to Upgrade 32 bit to 64 bit in Windows 7 - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PI_UwJoFcU0)

Answer (score 0):

<s>Yes</s> No, you need to upgrade the OS to 64-bit